# Why 'nrow()' function doesn't seem to work within 'summarise()' function?

Tags: r

See the below code:

```
library(dslabs)
data(gapminder)
gapminder %>%
  filter(year %in% c(2010, 2015) & !is.na(population)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(weight = nrow(population))
```

Why is it giving me an error: "*Column `weight` is of unsupported type NULL*"?

`nrow()` accepts a **vector** as an argument, and here `population` is a **vector** inside `summarise()` function. So, I wonder why it doesn't work?

**Note:** I know the alternatives to `nrow()` here, and I am not looking for alternative codes which would work. My question is conceptual and specifically pertains to the '**Why**'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing `nrow` to a column name which is `NULL`. See for example:

```
nrow(mtcars$mpg)
#NULL
```

`nrow` accepts a dataframe and not a vector:

```
nrow(mtcars)
#[1] 32
```

However, there is also a `NROW` function which accepts a vector so here you can use that instead:

```
library(dplyr)

gapminder %>%
  filter(year %in% c(2010, 2015) & !is.na(population)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(weight = NROW(population))
```

---

But if you are using `dplyr` and want to count the number of rows in each group there are some dedicated functions for them in `dplyr` ecosystem like:

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(year %in% c(2010, 2015) & !is.na(population)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(weight =n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   year weight
#  <int>  <int>
#1  2010    185
#2  2015    185
```

OR with `count`:

```
gapminder %>%
  filter(year %in% c(2010, 2015) & !is.na(population)) %>%
  count(year)
```

Comment: How is `nrow()` supposed to work then? And I didn't understand your first sentence, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Oops! Mega facepalm! From the documentation, it's totally not clear that `nrow()` only works with dataframes.

Comment: @HemanthBakaya The documenation of `nrow` and `NROW` is on the same page. So you might be confused because of that. `nrow` works on dataframes and `NROW` works on both dataframe and vectors but they are different functions.

Answer (score 1):

`summarize` requires the results of its summary functions to have a result of length 1, and a valid column type.

`nrow`, applied to a vector, returns `NULL`, which has length 0, `class` of `NULL`, and `type` `NULL`, which is not valid column type.

```
> x = 1:3
> nrow(x)
NULL
> length(nrow(x))
[1] 0
> class(nrow(x))
[1] "NULL"
> typeof(nrow(x))
[1] "NULL"
```

Comment: Doesn't `nrow` returns an integer, which is equal to the no. of rows?

Comment: `nrow`, applied to a **data frame or matrix**, returns an integer which is the number of rows. `nrow`, applied to a vector, does not. (Technically, vectors don't have rows, they just have a length.) Since you specified **vector** in your question and said you weren't interested in alternatives, I avoided that in the question. Perhaps you're thinking of `NROW`, which is friendlier to vectors?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Oops! Mega facepalm! From the documentation, it's totally not clear that nrow() only works with dataframes.